# iOS Image Viewer like Photo app

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit

I am developing an app that has an internal gallery with some images.

What I want to achieve is exactly a result that behaves and looks like the Apple Photo app image viewer.

[image: Example]

With a collection view I implemented the gallery images with thumbnails and now *I would like to show the image on fullscreen on press*.

The image viewer should have *exactly* the Apple's Photo behavior:

- Full screen on single tap,
- Delete, Share button etc...
- Pinch to zoom, double tap zoom...

My question is. *Is that really possible that such a common feature is not already given by iOS?* Is there maybe a view controller already build in that we can use but I am not aware of?

I know there are some libraries around that make such thing, **but I'm wondering if there's already something given.**

Comment: What did you end up doing to get this working?

Comment: Custom implementation. Unfortunately I didn't find anything done already.

Comment: I ended up using https://github.com/nytimes/NYTPhotoViewer for my needs